# Supplying remote JSON data for Typeahead / Bloodhound with Django / Python

Tags: json, django, ajax, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm trying to replicate functionality of [this Typeahead remote example](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote), but I can't figure out how to supply the data in the way Typeahead / Bloodhound wants it, nor what `datumTokenizer` or `queryTokenizer` are for.

In Python / Django views.py I've got:

```py
nouns = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear']
return JsonResponse({'results': nouns})
```

reaching the site as:

```json
{"results": ["apple", "banana", "pear"]}
```

Yet [for 'kings' the example returns](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/queries/kings.json):

```json
[{"year": "1949","value":"All the Kings Men","tokens":["All","the","Kings","Men"]}]
```

Need we return it in this format? If so, how? How can we make a simple replication of the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: for practical use `return HttpResponse(nouns)`, or `return JsonResponse(nouns, safe=False)`.

If concerned for security send it as a dict:

```py
noun_dicts = [{'suggestion':x} for x in nouns]
return JsonResponse({'results':noun_dicts})
```

And then parse the dict in JS.